# Apache rewrite causes two requests

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, httpd.conf

I noticed, that when we request a static resource, i.e. like this:
GET /MYAPP/css/navbar.css

it appears in apache logs as two lines:

> [20/Jul/2015:11:39:07 -0400] 10.72.123.1 TLSv1 AES256-SHA "GET
>   /MYAPP/css/navbar.css HTTP/1.1" 302 224 0/159
>
> [20/Jul/2015:11:39:07 -0400] 10.72.123.1 TLSv1 AES256-SHA "GET
>   /css/navbar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2846 0/364

This is something to do with a current rewrite rule set up in the configs:

```
RewriteRule ^/MYAPP/css/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/css/$1
...
<Directory "/var/www/myapp-static">
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Am I right that's something is wrong here? Each request to a static file results in two calls instead of one, does it decrease the apache overall perforamnce in any way? Whats the best practice to handle this?
As one of the solutions I see we can use links to static resources as /css/navbar.css directly, not via /MYAPP/css/navbar.css. But this will fail the application if it runs with no apache (as we do have some environments having no apache in it). 
Whats the best and typical solution is here?

Comment: Is the value of %{SERVER_NAME} different from the host name ?

Comment: @Zimmi I don't know to be honest.. how can I check the value of SERVER_NAME? Does it has something to do with a property ServerName defined inside the <VirtualHost> ?

Comment: @Zimmi actually it must be! ServerName in the VirtualHost is defined as loadbalanced domain name, while host can be different. So they should be the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `%{SERVER_NAME}` inside of the rule

```
RewriteRule ^/MYAPP/css/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/css/$1
```

is different from the host name, then Apache will make an external redirect, and write a log line, and a new request comes, that will be served. Many things can happen and depend on your setup, but my guess is now that you should give a try to a rule like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/MYAPP/css/(.*)$ /css/$1
```

What I think could be the problem is described in the Apache doc about [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), where they describe "Substitution", paragraph "Absolute URL".

If you needed the rule also for the https, you could use environment variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`.

Comment: thanks for that, having rule like you suggested fixes two entries in a log file. However, it feels the set up is still not perfect. When I access file like : https://<domainname>/MYAPP/css/navbar.css it takes two times more time in average than https://<domainname>/css/navbar.css - why that? Note, that I have a mod_jk module as well, which has this mount point: JKMount /MYAPP/* MYAPP

Comment: @javagirl good to know it solved the 2-lines problem. I'm quite confident that the performance impact you mention does not come from this rewrite. Especially as it seems you have it in http conf file, so this (simple) regex get compiled once at server startup (which is of course not the case for htaccess). I do not have knowledge with mod_jk, I won't be able to help you further on this. May be it sould be for another question, now that this redirect is cleaned ?